# Convert unicode string to utf8

Tags: iphone, unicode, utf-8, nsstring

When I get a string of the form \u043F\u043F (Unicode), how do I convert it to a readable NSUT8String? Here is my code (that fails when these are non English characters):

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

    NSString *theStr = [[NSString alloc]  initWithBytes:[receivedData bytes]
                                                  length:[receivedData length] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(theStr);
}
```

When the string is in English characters everything is fine - but when it is in Unicode format it fails to give me a readable string (but remains in a Unicode format).

What do you think?

---

EDIT:

I realized I didn't give enough info on what I'm trying to do. I am trying to use youtube's way of getting auto-suggested keywords when you use the search box (nothing official, just used a sniffer to find out). Here it is:

```
http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?hl=en&client=youtube&hjson=t&ds=yt&jsonp=window.yt.www.suggest.handleResponse&q=*******&cp=******
```

q is your query and cp is the length of q.

So basically when q is something in English it works fine. But when q has non English characters (Russian for example) this is what I get (from NSLog):

```
window.yt.www.suggest.handleResponse(["\u043F\u0440",[["\u043F\u0440\u0438\u043A\u043E\u043B\u044B","","0"],["\u043F\u0440\u043E\u0436\u0435\u043A\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043F\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0445\u0438\u043B\u0442\u043E\u043D","","1"],["\u043F\u0440\u043E\u0436\u0435\u043A\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043F\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0445\u0438\u043B\u0442\u043E\u043D 87","","2"],["\u043F\u0440\u043E\u0436\u0435\u043A\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043F\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0445\u0438\u043B\u0442\u043E\u043D 88","","3"],["\u043F\u0440\u043E\u0436\u0435\u043A\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043F\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0445\u0438\u043B\u0442\u043E\u043D 86","","4"],["\u043F\u0440\u043E\u0436\u0435\u043A\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043F\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0445\u0438\u043B\u0442\u043E\u043D 85","","5"],["\u043F\u0440\u043E\u0436\u0435\u043A\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043F\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0445\u0438\u043B\u0442\u043E\u043D 89","","6"],["\u043F\u0440\u043E\u0436\u0435\u043A\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043F\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0445\u0438\u043B\u0442\u043E\u043D 84","","7"],["\u043F\u0440\u0438\u043A\u043E\u043B\u044B \u0432 \u043F\u0440\u044F\u043C\u043E\u043C \u044D\u0444\u0438\u0440\u0435","","8"],["\u043F\u0440\u043E\u0436\u0435\u043A\u0442\u043E\u0440\u043F\u0435\u0440\u0438\u0441\u0445\u0438\u043B\u0442\u043E\u043D 90","","9"]],{}])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
@interface NSString 
{
     - (__strong const char *)UTF8String;  // Convenience to return
                                           // null-terminated UTF8 representation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this may help..

```
NSString *yourString = "\u043F\u0440\u0438\u043A\u043E\u043B\u044B";
NSArray *unicodeArray = [yourString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\u"];
NSMutableString *finalString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@""];
for (NSString *unicodeString in unicodeArray) {
    if (![unicodeString isEqualToString:@""]) {
        unichar codeValue;
        [[NSScanner scannerWithString:unicodeString] scanHexInt:&codeValue];
        NSString* betaString = [NSString stringWithCharacters:&codeValue length:1]; 
        [finalString appendString:betaString];
    }
} 
//finalString should have encoded one
```